# how to include css file to templates (.phtml file )in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

[image]

I wanted to place the contents of style tag in a seperate folder and wanted to include it into this `customtext.phtml` file.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you separate css file in your module/theme?

Answer (score 8):

You can add css file in phtml file using below line,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('css/mystyle.css')?>">
```

where path of **mystyle.css** will be at below location,

```
app/design/frontend/{Packagename}/{themenane}/web/css/mystyle.css
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have my customtext.phtml file inside my Magento_Search directory. Should I need to give the full path of css file in href ??

Comment: If I wanted to add a javascript file how should I do it..?

Comment: Try with code, <script  type="text/javascript"><?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('js/myscript.js')?></script>

Comment: sorry Its not working.. !!

Comment: <script src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('js/myscript.js')?>"></script> try with this formula

Comment: Iam getting Like :(Reload the page to get source for:/pub/static/version1501742739/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_AU/css/index.css)

Comment: if you are using modules you can use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('MODULENAME::css/mystyle.css')?>">`

Answer (score 5):

You should avoid add styles to template. It not good for maintaince and hard to debug in future

For your purposes
Option add css styles to templates
Ex: styles.phtml

```
/** @var $block your block class extend \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template **/
<style type="text/css">
   // Your css code here
</style>
```

Option include file css in template

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="head.additional.custom.styles" template="styles/style.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="file_name" xsi:type="string">yourstyle.css</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>    
    </body>
</page>
```

Block `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` is my example. Use your own block to get url, use block class example as ancenstor

Template style.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCssUrl() ?>"/>
```

First option for test. You should use second one

Answer (score 2):

Follow below steps.

Create css file at the below path.

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/customcss.css
```

Create `default_head_blocks.xml` file if not exist at below path:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

Put below code in `default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <css src="css/customcss.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: so shall we use classes in any module by just mentioning class name in the tag??!!